# How to Display Hyperlinked Attributes in Breadcrumbs in magento?

Tags: magento, attributes, breadcrumbs

http://wahid-palerain.blogspot.in/2010/07/displaying-products-filter-attributes.html

I followed this code but attributes are not hyperlinked and not inline 
Can anyone please help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

```
'link' key and its corresponding value of the array provides the hyperlink action. Refer the following code snippet:

// adding 'home'’ with link
$breadcrumbs->addCrumb(
'home',
 array(
'label'=>$this->__('Home'),
'title'=>$this->__('Home'), 
'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()
)
);
echo $breadcrumbs->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Can You please elaborate how to do it,i am new to magento

Comment: to display customised breadcrumbs, use the above code in .phtml file. Here i have creted a breadcrumb with the name 'Home' and on clicking 'Home', page will be redirected to starting page i.e, Mage::getBaseUrl(). Change 'Home' and 'Mage::getBaseUrl()' as per your requirement.

Comment: i have already the code for home page link,i want link for attributes which we use to filter Ashritha